# How to register broadcast receiver from Manifest?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I want to create a background app with no UI.
So, I have a broadcast receiver and I am trying to register it from the manifest. This is what I did inside my manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name="background.broadcastReceivers.GPSStartedReceiver">

        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action
                android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED"
                android:enabled="true"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

But when I run the app the broadcast receiver is never being registered.
When I register my receiver from a test activity, it works fine.
Why could this be happening?

This is what I am doing inside the test activity:

```
    private GPSStartedReceiver receiver = new GPSStartedReceiver();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Register a broadcast receiver which listens to GPS provider changes
        this.registerReceiver(receiver,
                new IntentFilter("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED"));
    }
```

Comment: What are you doing in the activity that works OK?

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to create a background app with no UI.

That is not practical.

> But when I run the app the broadcast receiver is never being registered. When I register my receiver from a test activity, it works fine. Why could this be happening?

Manifest-registered receivers do not work upon installation. They only work after something uses an explicit `Intent` to start up one of the app's components. For 99.9% of apps, that is their home screen launcher activity.

Comment: Thank you! Could I register the receiver from another app, which is going to have the UI?

Comment: @Manos: I am not quite certain why you are splitting this into two apps. That being said, the other app is welcome to send a broadcast or start a service in your no-UI app, using an explicit `Intent`. It might do that when it detects that your no-UI app has been installed. At that point, your no-UI app's manifest-registered receiver will work.

Comment: I am splitting it because it is a project for my University and I have been asked to. I wouldn't split it otherwise, I can't see any reason except for practise.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a minimal app with the following manifest entry:

```
<receiver android:name="test.Receiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And test.Receiver class:

```
package test;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("@@@", "here");
        }
    }
```

My log message prints when I toggled the GPS on the device. Maybe your manifest XML has too much extra stuff in it?

Comment: I have created the receiver class but it does not work. The problem is in the registration. I can't register the receiver without an activity.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested and create a simple test app with the above samples?